# StreamReader ReadLine

Tags: c#

I send from Raspberry to C# a packet with content "\n%d\r"
Then, I read in C# by `StreamReader` with `ReadLine()` method. I receive 2 messages alternately, one with the value %d in, and one empty. That reduces the performance of my program. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Why do you send the `\n` and `\r` and why do you send it the way you do? a line ending is normally denoted by one of `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n`.

Comment: Is `\n%d\r` **verbatim**? Or do you mean you _actually_ used it as a `(s)printf` format-specifier and `%d` is actually some integer value? If so, then please show us the **actual raw bytes** that were sent down the wire.

Comment: please provide a fully reproducible example